# Django unittest failing with table not found

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, django-models

```
from django.test import TestCase
from data.models import Projects

class ProjectTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_project(self):

        Projects.objects.create(name="lion")
        lion = Projects.objects.get(name="lion")
        self.assertEqual(lion.count(), 1)
```

I've a sample testcase like above and when I run with this command 
python manage.py test -v3 tests

It is throwing the bellow error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yekabathula/workspace/roster/tests/test_project.py", line 12, in test_animals_can_speak
    Projects.objects.create(name="lion")
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 348, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 710, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 738, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 822, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 861, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 920, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 963, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 202, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'test_nst2015.projects' doesn't exist")

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.031s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default' ('test_nst2015')...
```

Comment: Do you have migrations for your models?

Comment: This looks like an issue with settings, not tests. Try to open the shell and create the object in the shell (`./manage.py shell` and then import the model and create an instance).

Answer (score 1):

First: 
Run the [makemigrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#the-commands).

Try this :

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Second: `lion` is a `Projects object`, not a queryset.
If you want get the count of Projects, try change the assert to:

```
self.assertEqual(Projects.objects.count(), 1)
```

Comment: I've tried that but no luck. After applying migrations do I need to do anything?

Comment: what the django version? the migrations folder was created?

Comment: Django 1.8, yes migrations are applied. But still getting that error.

Comment: the same error? you changed the assert? can you updated the post with the block code of this (test_animals_can_speak)

Comment: _italic_ **bold** `from django.test import TestCase
from data.models import Projects

class ProjectTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_project(self):

        Projects.objects.create(name="lion")
        self.assertEqual(Projects.objects.count(), 1).
`
Same error. But I'm seeing the below line in the error
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: utils, frontend, tests, fixtures
  Apply all migrations: contenttypes, api, tastypie, auth, sessions

Comment: You have the app, on installed apps?, please, update the POST, with the code of migration.

Comment: `python manage.py makemigrations api
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tastypie/fields.py:7: 
  from django.utils import importlib

Migrations for 'api':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model BrLocations
    - Create model BrWorkdays
    - Create model BusinessRules
    - Create model Dispositions
    - Create model Locations
    - Create model LogHistory
    - Create model Projects
    - Create model ProjectTeam
    - Create model ShiftTimes
    - Create model Users
    - Create model UserWorkdays
    - Create model Workdays`